# Selected Index Changed event not firing both Autopostback property

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

In my Dropdownlist Selected index change event not firing.Here  i use auto post back true &
View state also true.But Selected Index Changed Event not firing

My Code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="AdminEagleViewLogin.aspx.cs" Inherits="AdminEagleViewLogin" %>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <style>
        body{padding-top:20px;}
    </style>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
          User :  <asp:DropDownList ID="drpusr" runat="server"  Visible="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="drpusr_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true" ></asp:DropDownList>
       Password: <asp:Label ID="lbluserpw" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Please sign in</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form">
                    <fieldset>
                        <div class="form-group">
                           <asp:TextBox ID="txtusr" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                             <asp:TextBox ID="txtpw" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input name="remember" type="checkbox" value="Remember Me"> Remember Me
                            </label>
                        </div>
                     <asp:CheckBox ID="chkremember" runat="server" Visible="false" class="remchkbox" />
                         <asp:Button ID="submit" runat="server" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" Text="Submit" OnClick="submit_Click" />
                    </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

ServerSide
User bind to Dropdown is working.

```
   public partial class AdminEagleViewLogin : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindUsers();
        //lbluserpw.Text = Membership.Provider.GetPassword(drpusr.SelectedValue, String.Empty);
    }
    protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (Membership.ValidateUser(txtusr.Text, txtpw.Text))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(txtusr.Text, chkremember.Checked);
            string[] CurrentUserRole = Roles.GetRolesForUser(txtusr.Text);

            var admin = "Administrator";
            var manager = "Manager";
            var user = "User";

            if (CurrentUserRole.Contains(admin))
            {
                Response.Redirect("Administrator.aspx");
            }
            else if (CurrentUserRole.Contains(manager))
            {
                Response.Redirect("Manager.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("UserPage.aspx");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("AdminEagleViewLogin.aspx");

        }
    }

    protected void BindUsers()
    {
        DataAccess da = new DataAccess();
        drpusr.DataSource = da.GetUsers();
        drpusr.DataTextField = "UserName";
        drpusr.DataValueField = "UserId";
        drpusr.DataBind();

        drpusr.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("-- Select User --", "0"));
        drpusr.Items.RemoveAt(1);

    }

    protected void drpusr_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       lbluserpw.Text = Membership.Provider.GetPassword(drpusr.SelectedValue, String.Empty);


 }
}
```

Comment: check if you have EnableViewState="true" in your page, if it's set to false it will not fire the event.

Comment: @BlackBaron Not set EnableViewState

Comment: @BlackBaron I checked it with EnableViewState="false" but no luck

Comment: set EnableViewState="true", it works well with me. if it didn't work then please update your question with the page markup and how you're binding the dropdownlist.

Comment: @BlackBaron Post Edited.pls look

Comment: we're almost there to solve this, can you please put the line just before <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">? which contains: <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54828/discussion-between-black-baron-and-techguy).

Comment: @BlackBaron OP edited.

Comment: regsiter asp.net again on IIS - do you have the asp_net folder ?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't put a form element inside another form:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form">
  <fieldset>
    ...
    <asp:Button ID="submit" runat="server" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" Text="Submit" OnClick="submit_Click" />
   </fieldset>
 </form>
```

remove the inner form.

**[Update]**

Another problem is the "ID" property of the button.
change it to something else, other than "submit".

Comment: inner form removed... & Field Set removed But still having a problem

Comment: did u try changing button's ID?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindUsers();
    }
}
```